# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LoginForm.UserInfo_Result>'

Tags: c#

I am new in MVC. I am tryinng to load username from databse to dropdown list. but get error in my model class-

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

My Model class is-

DropdownClass.cs
Here is my model class code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using LoginForm.Models;

    namespace LoginForm.Models
    {
        public class DropdownClass
        {

            ConsumerBankingEntities db = new ConsumerBankingEntities();
            public IEnumerable<UserInfo_Result> GetUserInfo()
            {
                var query = (from s in db.UserInfo()
                            select s);
                return query.ToList();

            }
        } 
    }
```

My controller name is

LoginController.Cs

Here is the controller code-

```
using LoginForm.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace LoginForm.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {

        ConsumerBankingEntities db = new ConsumerBankingEntities();


        public ActionResult Dropdown(string returnUrl)
        {

            DropdowncCass dp = new DropdowncCass();
            var allName = dp.GetUserInfo();
            ViewBag.AllNameList = allName;
            Session["allName"] = allName;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

            return RedirectToAction("Welcome","Login");

        }


        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Welcome()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

How can get over this error?

Comment: Is this a compilation error? In which line it occurs.

Comment: Yes. It is. in my model class. red line appears under  " return query.ToList();" @SeM

Comment: Issue is you are returning a different type via linq query from `UserInfo_Result`, which is why there's an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `db.UserInfo()` method returns collection of `string` and `ToString()` makes it `List<string>`, but method `GetUserInfo()` returns `IEnumerable<UserInfo_Result>`.

You should either change your `db.UserInfo()` to return `IEnumerable<UserInfo_Result>`, or construct `IEnumerable<UserInfo_Result>` before returning (at `GetUserInfo`), or just change return type of `GetUserInfo` to `List<string>`. It dependes on what you need.

Comment: Why do you think its a `string`, it can be anything else, its just a type mismatch

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Because of title of question - _"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LoginForm.UserInfo_Result>'"_

Comment: Not sure if the title is recently modified, types were not visible earlier, but in any case linq query will not yield `IEnumerable<string>`, until and unless `db.UserInfo` is a string collection, but here it seems to be a database table

Comment: @MrinalKamboj nope, it was as it is, from beginning. `db.UserInfo` for sure is `string` collection and calling `ToList()` on it will return `List<string>`, which will not match to return type of `GetUserInfo`. And yes, `db.UserInfo()` is can be any collection of strings, I will edit.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Also note, that `db.UserInfo()` has a method signature.

Comment: Then a nomenclature / naming convention issue, since `db` is predominantly EF or similar db context, which are used across application, not for a class object

Comment: @MrinalKamboj sure, he probably named his db class `ConsumerBankingEntities`.